# Let $(AEFH) \cap AM=L $. Show that $B,H,L,C$ is cyclic

Tags: geometry

Let $ABC$ be an acute angled triangle, Let $M$ be the midpoint of $BC$ . Let $D,E,F$ be the foot of the altitudes in side $BC$,$CA$,$BA$. Let $(AEFH) \cap AM=L $. Show that $B$,$H,$L$,$C$ is cyclic.

Here's a diagram:[image]

I tried angle chase but was stuck

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: Solution using inversion: Note that there is a standard inversion about A that interchanges B and F, D and H, and C and E. Therefore, this inversion interchanges circles BHC and FDE, circle AFHE and line BDC, and fixes the line AM. Therefore L' ( := circle AFHE  intersect circle BHC) goes to M under this inversion (nine point circle?). Thus A, L', M are collinear and L=L'.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

The pink angles are equal, meaning isosceles triangles $\triangle AOE$ and $\triangle BME$ are similar. Therefore $OE\perp EM$ so $EM$ is tangent to circle $O$.

$EM^2=ML\cdot MA \implies BM^2=ML\cdot MA$ so $\triangle MBL$ and $\triangle MAB$ similar so the cyan angles are all equal, and the result proven.

Comment: Great solution !

Answer (score 1):

Okay, here's the brief sketch of the solution I got, not angle chase though .

Note that $HLDM$ is cyclic [why ?]. It is also well known that $(BEFC)$ is cyclic [why ?]

Now, consider the circles $(AFHEL),(HLDM),(BEFC)$ . By radical axis lemme, we know that radical axis of $(AFHEL),(HLDM),(BEFC)$ i.e $EF,HL,DM$ concur . Let's say they concur at point $G$.

By Power of Point, we get that $\Bbb {P} (G, (BFEC))=\Bbb {P} (G, (HLDM))$ [ why? hint: what is radical axis ?]

So $GB\cdot GC=GH\cdot GL \implies$ by converse of POP , $BCHL$ is cyclic.

Here's a diagram:
[image]

Comment: Thanks... this was the required solution

Answer (score 1):

Let $H'$ and $L'$ be points symmetric to $H$ and $L$ with respect to $M$. Then $BH \parallel CH'$ and since $BH \perp AC$, it follows that $AC \perp CH'$. Similarly, $AB \perp BH'$. Hence $B$ and $C$ lie on the circle $\omega$ with diameter $AH'$.

Now, $HL \perp AL$ because $L$ lies on the circle with diameter $AH$. Moreover $HL \parallel H'L'$, hence $H'L' \perp AL'$ and therefore $L'$ lies on $\omega$. It follows that $B,H,L,C$ lie on the circle symmetric to $\omega$ with respect to $M$.

[image]

Comment: Great solution !